# SVM model overfitting?

Tags: python, svm, modeling, scikit-learn, overfitting

I have a multi-class (10 classes) classification problem. I am using one-vs-rest SVM modeling with sklearn.svm.SVC.

**I want to know whether my model is over-fitting**.

For train set accuracy is 100% and for test set its 97%+.

To analyze the model, I did the following:

1. I plotted probability (using [predict_proba()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.predict_proba), that works as expalined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111408/how-does-sklearn-svm-svcs-function-predict-proba-work-internally)).

In all the following plots, colors and legends represent the 10 classes, with labels ranging in 0-9.

The figure below shows the probabilities of true class for the train set instances:
[image: Probabilities for the train set instances. y-axis: probability, x-axis: indexes of the samples]

The following figure shows the probabilities of true class for the test set instances:
[image: Probabilities for the test set instances. y-axis: probability]

**Observation**: The train set contains very few instances with probability < 0.95.
Whereas test set has many instances with low probabilities for true class. **Should this be treated as over-fitting of the model**?

2. Similarly, I plotted distance (using [decision_function()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.decision_function)) from separating hyperplane.

Train set distance of true class from separating hyperplane:
[image: Train set distance from separating hyperplane. y-axis: distance]

Test set distance of true class from separating hyperplane:
[image: Test set distance from separating hyperplane]

3. Then I compared the probabilities of true class vs best of the rest class (which I call as best alternate class).
   X-label represents true class probability. And y-label represents the probability of its corresponding best alternate class.

Probability comparison on train set:
[image: Probability comparison on train set]

Probability comparison on test set:
[image: Probability comparison on test set]

4. Similarly, I compared the distances from the separating hyperplane.
   X-label and y-label conventions are similar to the ones above for comparing probabilities.

Distance comparison on train set:
[image: Distance comparison on train set]

Distance comparison on test set:
[image: Distance comparison on test set]

Comment: Did you find the problem yet? I have a similar problem

Comment: Its been a long time since I posted this question. If I remember correctly, I didn't got a solution.